# docker-compose volume not appearing in container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, boot2docker

I'm trying to build a stack with one `docker-compose` that should contain another containers inside. This is to run a development environment with all my projects inside.

So the problem is the volume with application source isn't appearing on built image.

```
MacOS Sierra
Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.8.0
```

my directory tree

```
/dockers                 <======= one directory with all docker files for each project

  docker-compose.yml     <======= The main image

  /project1              <======= dockerfile for each project
    Dockerfile
  /project2
    Dockerfile
  /project3
    Dockerfile

/project1              <======= project1 source folder
  test.txt
/project2
/project3
```

my docker-compose.yml

```
project1:
  build: ./project1
  volumes:
    - ../project1/:/src
```

my dockerfile for `project1`

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN mkdir -p /src

WORKDIR /src
RUN echo "---------------------"
RUN ls -la
RUN echo "---------------------"
```

So I try to build the `docker-compose` file

```
$ sudo docker-compose build --no-cache
```

And then it shows an empty folder when I expect `test.txt` file

```
Building express
ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile
➜  docker git:(master) ✗ sudo docker-compose build --no-cache
Building project1
Step 1/7 : FROM python:2.7
 ---> ca388cdb5ac1
Step 2/7 : RUN mkdir -p /src
 ---> Running in 393a462f7a44
 ---> 4fbeb32d88b3
Removing intermediate container 393a462f7a44
Step 3/7 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> 03ce193577ab
Removing intermediate container b1cd746b699a
Step 4/7 : RUN echo "--------------------------"
 ---> Running in 82df8a512c90
----------------------------
 ---> 6dea58ba5051
Removing intermediate container 82df8a512c90
Step 5/7 : RUN ls -la
 ---> Running in 905417d0cd19
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 23 17:12 .                    <====== EMPTY :(
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Mar 23 17:12 ..                   <====== EMPTY :(
 ---> 53764caffb1a
Removing intermediate container 905417d0cd19
Step 6/7 : RUN echo "-----------------------------"
 ---> Running in 110e765d102a
----------------------------
 ---> b752230fd6dc
Removing intermediate container 110e765d102a
Step 7/7 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Running in 1cfe2e80d282
 ---> 5e3e740d5a9a
Removing intermediate container 1cfe2e80d282
Successfully built 5e3e740d5a9a
```

Answer (score 1):

Volumes are runtime configurations in Docker. Because they are configurable, if you were to reference volumes during the build phase you would essentially be creating a potentially uncheckable broken dependency.

I'm sure there is a more technical reason - but it really shouldn't be done.  Move all that stuff to the runtime setup command and you should be OK.

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you explain a bit more detailed about how to do with your suggestion?